# Rails naming convention: "Miss", "Kiss", "Bus", etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

How should I name my models when they need to be named after a word which ends with "s" (link Bus, for example)? I suppose rails will pluralize it putting another "s" to end of the word. But I'd like my table to be called "buses" instead of "buss".

Comment: rails will name your database as buses, kisses etc...

Comment: Thanks, Jorge, that will do the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails will handle this for you by using `String#pluralize` when generating models:

```
% rails g model bus                                                                                                                                                                            
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20130205170847_create_buses.rb
      create    app/models/bus.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create      spec/models/bus_spec.rb
```

And the resulting migration:

```
# ...
    create_table :buses do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
# ...
```

You can try it yourself in `rails c` too:

```
[1] pry(main)> 'bus'.pluralize
=> "buses"
[2] pry(main)> 'miss'.pluralize
=> "misses"
[3] pry(main)> 'kiss'.pluralize
=> "kisses"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But I meant pluralization on creating models. Will it work the same way?

Comment: Yes, if your model is called "bus", then Rails will create a table called "buses". I added a snippet from the migration too.